# How do I derive this polygonal function from sample values?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have 4 parameters with 16 sample data points each. When I plot them, I get this:

[image: Plot of 4 parameters with 16 sample data points]

The curves lead me to suspect that all these of 64 data point are derived from one polygonal function with 4 different scalings.

- What type of polygonal function is this?
- What is the best way to try to derive the original equation from these sample values?

Context:

- I'm trying to re-engineer an undocumented picture file-format and these values seem to describe the scaling factors for the lens-correction function.
- The function is likely f(x)=a*x^2 + b*x^4 + c*x^6, the relevant input range is likely [0-1], i.e., the 16 values are steps of 1/16=0.0625. But I'm guessing here, could be different.
- The exact (as per double-precision) 64 data points I have decoded are [here](http://pastebin.com/e4CEmRj5).

Many thanks!

Comment: Hopefully useful to you:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Make use of The Lagrange interpolating polynomial.

For any points $(x_1,f(x_1)),...,(x_n,f(x_n))$ on a polynomial $P(x)$,

we have $P(x)=\sum_{j=1}^nP_j(x)$

where $P_j(x)=y_j\prod_{k=1,k\neq{j}}^{n}\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}$.

In your case, $n=16,x_0=0,x_1=1,...,x_{16}=15$

Let $Q(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{x-x_k}=(x-0)(x-1)...(x-15)$

So $$P_j(x)=\frac{Q(x)}{(x-x_j)Q(x_j)}\cdot{y_j}$$

For $Q(x_j)$, by observation, we have:

$$Q(x_j)=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot{j!}\cdot{(15-j)!}$$

Comment: Thank you. If I understand the Lagrange logic correctly, it finds a polynomial function that passes through all points perfectly, potentially yielding a high degree function. I am looking more for an approximation and am willing to accept small errors. Or the other way around: I believe there is a simple polynomial function with 3 (or so) factors that yields these values. The values itself might have lost some precision due to encoding. So is there some algorithm that give me the best approximation (i.e., minimises error) if I say I want a polynomial of n-th degree? Thanks